# How to get assigned role for an item in C# code?

Tags: security

I assigned a role to a form. I need to get that extranet\Marketing from the form item. I tried to check the Security property and I was not able to get that. What is the right way to get the roles assigned to an item, in this case, a form?

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned you tried something - can you share what you tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following code to get all the roles assigned to the item.

```
item.Security.GetAccessRules()
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a user have access to a Sitecore item, you can use this code.

```
// Get Sitecore item
var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home/item");
 
// Check if the current context user 
// have read access to the item
bool canRead = item.Access.CanRead();
```

And Check if a named user has read access use this code.

```
using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(@"extranet\username", true))
{
  bool canRead = item.Access.CanRead();
}
```

Refer to [this](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2018/11/09/sitecore-check-access-and-roles-programatically/) for more details.

Hope this helps.